# Reading unsaved data from Excel using python

Tags: python, excel, pandas, numpy, datatables

I have an excel table, the data in which is updated online, is it possible to read new data without saving the exel table before this every time?
I would be very happy if there is a solution to this problem.

The data in the Excel table is received via the DDE connection.

Comment: So you want : read data from an open Excel file in Python ?

Comment: Yes, I need to read the file without saving it, as the data updates too quickly. I tried to save the file using macros, but in the first place it is too slow (1 time per second maximum), in the other it is not reliable

Comment: Check [here](https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-read-data-from-an-open-Excel-file-in-Python) if something can help you. Hope I could help.